# Result of order for same query appearing different in MySQL 5.x.x and 8.x.x versions

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

My staging environment has MySQL 5.x.x version and production has 8.x.x version. MySQL query is written in Codeigniter 4 MVC.

When i execute code containing MySQL query on Staging environment, the sequence of rows are appearing different than the query executed on production. Both environment have same DB data. I could not use ORDER BY clause because further i'm using GROUP BY in same query (JOIN) which should return me 1st appeared row. And because of different IDs found after GROUP BY, Staging and Production server behavior is appearing different.

Below is query -

```
SELECT `A`.`qam_id`, `B`.`care_giver_name`, `B`.`care_cli_id`, `E`.* 
FROM `tbl_client_qtly_assessment_master` AS `A` 
JOIN `tbl_care_note_review_form` AS `B` ON `A`.`qam_id` = `B`.`care_qam_id` 
JOIN `tbl_clients` AS `C` ON `A`.`qam_cli_id` = `C`.`cli_id` 
JOIN `tbl_client_emergency_contact` AS `D` ON `B`.`care_giver_name` = `D`.`emc_id` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_generate_stipend_payment` AS `E` ON `E`.`stipend_qam_id` = `A`.`qam_id` 
WHERE `cli_dcc_id` = '69' 
 AND `qam_type` = 'Care Note' 
 AND `qam_status` = 'ACTIVE' 
 AND B.care_giver_name = 14385 
 AND( `care_date_sun` >= "2024-01-07" 
  AND `care_date_sat` <= "2024-01-20" ) 
 AND `A`.`qam_complete_status` != 'STRIKED' 
GROUP BY `B`.`care_giver_name`, `B`.`care_cli_id` 
ORDER BY CAST(cli_client_id AS UNSIGNED) ASC LIMIT 20;
```

In above query, table 'tbl_generate_stipend_payment' has LEFT JOIN and will return multiple rows. But at end of query we have GROUP BY clause, which will pick 1st row from tbl_generate_stipend_payment table.

Below are the order of result when i removed GROUP BY-

Result on 5.x.x -
[image]

Result on 8.x.x -
[image]

So, Staging & Production servers are picking 1st row after applying GROUP BY which are different IDs when compare. Result need to have in same order so that row after GROUP BY should return same data in Staging & Production.
Please suggest if there any solution.

Comment: It's likely the same query has different execution plan in 5.x and 8.x even with the same data set, as MySQL8 has an improved optimizer.  Please add `explain` at the beginning of your query and give us the result.

Comment: If you "can't" use ORDER BY, then you really have no reason to _expect_ any specific order. ("can't" in quotes, because so far you have only stated that it wasn't possible, without giving any proper details.)

Comment: I have added more information to get idea what needs to achieve.

Comment: Your previous query was picking the first row only by accident. When you use GROUP BY, the "first" row is only the first row read in index order. So if the optimizer changes in version 8.0 such that it chooses a different index, the order it reads rows may be different.

Comment: A good solution in MySQL 8.0 is to use window functions to rank the rows, then filter for rows with rank 1. I show an example in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/20860